# Less than full screen launch image (Default.png)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering, if you don't use a full screen image for your launch image (i.e. Default.png), will your image get stretched? For instance, I want to use a 320x460 image (reusing an image file that's already in my app), will that get stretched to fit 320x480?

Comment: it just wont accept it as the image in xcode. You have to use one of the correct size

Comment: I'm wondering, why don't you try it yourself instead of asking a question and waiting for an answer?

Comment: @Novarg - I had been but was getting odd results so wanted some verification. Turns out it kept loading one of my old launch files into memory even after I deleted it, that's why I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a 320 x 460 launch image and Apple was fine with it. The binary passed validation and then the app was approved by the review team.